# Javascript map returning function

Tags: javascript

I have an interesting problem with a map that is broken in Firefox.  When I test if an empty map has the string "watch" it will return true and return the function watch().  I want that to return false  since I haven't added the key "watch" to the map. A quick example

I normally create a basic map like

```
var myMap = {}
myMap["apple"] = 1;
myMap["pear"] = 2;
```

And to test if the map has the object I would write

```
if ("apple" in myMap) { ... }
```

And the problem is when I want to add the string "watch" to the map if the map doesn't all ready contain it.  So when I check to see if the map contains "watch" it returns true.

```
if ("watch" in myMap) { ... }
// This also returns true.  and returns the function watch()
```

Any ideas on how to avoid this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Objects have built in properties, [Object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) being one of them, use a property name that isn't already in use, and it solves itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because an object literal inherits from the Object prototype. You can create an empty object, that inherits from nothing:

```
var myMap = Object.create(null);
```

Or check with `hasOwnProperty`:

```
if (myMap.hasOwnProperty('watch')) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  creating the empty object is what I needed to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
var myMap = {};
myMap["apple"] = 1;
myMap["pear"]=2;

if (myMap.hasOwnProperty("apple")) {

}

if (myMap.hasOwnProperty("watch")) {

}
```